# Any way to output HTTP headers saved as part of file body

Tags: php, http, header

Suppose a file saved on the disk:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 Jun 2012 22:11:14 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 1234
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html ....
```

Is there any builtin function in php to output the file while at the same time recognizing headers inside it and sending them correctly?

Comment: Well there is a way to read a file, parse it and then send headers and body separately. But a ready made solution could be more reliable. Also, why not to leave it to the browser to parse!!!

Comment: There is [`http_parse_message()`](http://php.net/http_parse_message), but doesn't quite do what you want. But any userland HTTP library (see PEAR) has prepared utility code for that, as it's basically a raw HTTP response in your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not exists but you can use the following

```
$file = "file.html";
var_dump(fileHeaders($file));
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' (length=15)
  1 => string 'Date: Thu, 28 Jun 2012 22:11:14 GMT' (length=35)
  2 => string 'Pragma: no-cache' (length=16)
  3 => string 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-store' (length=40)
  4 => string 'Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT' (length=38)
  5 => string 'Content-Length: 1234' (length=20)
  6 => string 'Connection: close' (length=17)
  7 => string 'Content-Type: text/html' (length=23)
  8 => string '' (length=0)
```

Function Used

```
function fileHeaders($file) {
    $content = file_get_contents($file, null, null, 0, 1000);
    $content = trim($content);
    if (stripos($content, "HTTP") === 0) {
        return array_map("trim", explode("\n", strtok($content, "<")));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You'll have to implement one on your own.